# SELECT COUNT(foreign ID) for each row in datatable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, select, count

I have datable where I store my dailyContent selection.
This is different for each day.

When I select more then one day, then I need to return items, which are the same for all days.

I have tried something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
                        (
                             SELECT
                                ( -- For count
                                SELECT COUNT(recipeId) AS [Count]
                                FROM DailyContentDish
                                WHERE
                                    (
                                        (weekDayId=@mon OR @mon IS NULL) OR
                                        (weekDayId=@tue OR @tue IS NULL) OR
                                        (weekDayId=@wed OR @wed IS NULL) OR
                                        (weekDayId=@thu OR @thu IS NULL) OR
                                        (weekDayId=@fri OR @fri IS NULL) OR
                                        (weekDayId=@sat OR @sat IS NULL) OR
                                        (weekDayId=@sun OR @sun IS NULL) 
                                    ) 
                                    GROUP BY DailyContentDish.recipeId
                                ) AS cnt, 
                                -- End for count
                                DailyContentDish.dailyContentDishId,
                                DailyContentDish.recipeId AS Rec, 
                                title, 
                                150 AS calories, 
                                defaultSmallImagePath,
                                activePreparationTime + passivePreparationTime AS overallPreparationTime,
                                CAST(
                                    CASE WHEN EXISTS
                                        (
                                        SELECT  DailyContentDishFavourite.dailyContentDishFavouriteId
                                        FROM DailyContentDishFavourite 
                                        WHERE DailyContentDishFavourite.dailyContentDishId = DailyContentDish.dailyContentDishId
                                        )
                                    THEN 1 
                                    ELSE 0
                                END 
                                AS BIT) AS isFavouriteWhenGeneratingMenu


                                FROM DailyContentDish
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                    RecipesTranslations ON RecipesTranslations.recipeId = DailyContentDish.recipeId
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                    RecipeAdditionalInformation ON RecipeAdditionalInformation.recipeId = DailyContentDish.recipeId
                    WHERE
                    isEnabled = 1 AND
                    mealId=@mealId AND 
                        (       
                                weekDayId=@mon OR
                                weekDayId=@tue OR
                                weekDayId=@wed OR
                                weekDayId=@thu OR
                                weekDayId=@fri OR
                                weekDayId=@sat OR
                                weekDayId=@sun
                                )

                            ) p
                            WHERE p.cnt = @daysCount
```

The problem is, that nested select which should return count returns it for all rows, not just one entry (each row, that is).
Since entries with recipeId are entered more then once I would like to know how many times are they entered.

```
SELECT
                                ( -- For count
                                SELECT COUNT(recipeId) AS [Count]
                                FROM DailyContentDish
                                WHERE
                                    (
                                        (weekDayId=@mon OR @mon IS NULL) OR
                                        (weekDayId=@tue OR @tue IS NULL) OR
                                        (weekDayId=@wed OR @wed IS NULL) OR
                                        (weekDayId=@thu OR @thu IS NULL) OR
                                        (weekDayId=@fri OR @fri IS NULL) OR
                                        (weekDayId=@sat OR @sat IS NULL) OR
                                        (weekDayId=@sun OR @sun IS NULL) 
                                    )  AND Something should be here (I guess)
                                    GROUP BY DailyContentDish.recipeId
                                ) AS cnt, 
                                -- End for count
```

This part should return COUNT of entries for each row I select - but it retuns me COUNT of all entries.

Or should I take a different path with this.
Any hint is greatly appreciated.

I am using MS SQL server 2008

EDIT:
this is whole stored procedure:

```
        @userId int,
        @languageId int,
        @mealId int,
        @mon int,
        @tue int,
        @wed int,
        @thu int,
        @fri int,
        @sat int,
        @sun int,
        @orderBy nvarchar(2),
        @pageSize int,
        @startRowIndex int

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @daysCount int
SET @daysCount = 0
IF (@mon IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @daysCount = @daysCount+1
    END
IF (@tue IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @daysCount = @daysCount+1
    END
IF (@wed IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @daysCount = @daysCount+1
    END
IF (@thu IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @daysCount = @daysCount+1
    END
IF (@fri IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @daysCount = @daysCount+1
    END
IF (@sat IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @daysCount = @daysCount+1
    END
IF (@sun IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @daysCount = @daysCount+1
    END


-- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT *
    FROM (
SELECT
    (
        SELECT [Count] = COUNT(recipeId) 
        FROM dbo.DailyContentDish d
        WHERE
        (
            ISNULL(@mon, weekDayId) = weekDayId OR
            ISNULL(@tue, weekDayId) = weekDayId OR
            ISNULL(@wed, weekDayId) = weekDayId OR
            ISNULL(@thu, weekDayId) = weekDayId OR
            ISNULL(@fri, weekDayId) = weekDayId OR
            ISNULL(@sat, weekDayId) = weekDayId OR
            ISNULL(@sun, weekDayId) = weekDayId 
        ) 
        GROUP BY d.recipeId
    ) AS cnt, 
    d.dailyContentDishId,
    d.recipeId AS Rec, 
    title, 
    150 AS calories, 
    defaultSmallImagePath,
    activePreparationTime + passivePreparationTime AS overallPreparationTime,
    CASE WHEN d2.dailyContentDishId IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isFavouriteWhenGeneratingMenu
FROM dbo.DailyContentDish d
LEFT JOIN dbo.RecipesTranslations r ON r.recipeId = d.recipeId
LEFT JOIN dbo.RecipeAdditionalInformation t ON t.recipeId = d.recipeId
LEFT JOIN dbo.DailyContentDishFavourite d2 ON d.dailyContentDishId = d2.dailyContentDishId
WHERE isEnabled = 1 
    AND mealId = @mealId 
    AND (       
        weekDayId = @mon OR
        weekDayId = @tue OR
        weekDayId = @wed OR
        weekDayId = @thu OR
        weekDayId = @fri OR
        weekDayId = @sat OR
        weekDayId = @sun
    )
    ) p
    WHERE p.cnt = @daysCount
```

Edit1: I have uploaded diagram:
[image: Database diagram]

Here is sample data (for meal Id = 1, this is also selected on form), explanation:
- recipe with ID 125 will be present on Monday (weekDayId = 1) and Saturday (weekDayId = 7). So, this recipe must be returned if I select only Monday OR if I select only Saturday OR if I select Monday and Saturday. If I also select any other day then ithis record is not returned.
- recipe with ID 105 must be returned when weekDays 1, 6 and 7 (Monday, Saturday, Sunday) are selected. Same as above, if any other day is selected then this record is not returned. 
[image: Sample data]

Comment: what does the table look like? is item the same as recipeId? Can you post schema + example data + your query on sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: New version: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4fbff/3

Comment: So one weekdayId can have multiple reciepId, is that it? Did you try this? SELECT count(*), weekdayId FROM DailyContentDish group by weekdayId

Comment: Yes, one weekDayId can have one dishId for one meal. There are more meals. I try to select entries for one day and for one meal. That way it works OK. BUT: when I try to select more days then only meals which are the same for that days (and meals) should be returned.

Comment: So, you want your count subquery to return the total count of meals on the matching day as the outer DailyContentDish row?

Comment: Yes, because this way I could select only entries, which matches the days that were selected. It seems we are pretty close to solution just below. I really appreciate help from all of you on this case ;)

Comment: I have updated question in order to be more understandable.

Comment: What would really is a display of expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Possible this help you -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.usp_GetDailyContentDish

    @userId INT,
    @languageId INT,
    @mealId INT,
    @mon INT,
    @tue INT,
    @wed INT,
    @thu INT,
    @fri INT,
    @sat INT,
    @sun INT,
    @orderBy NVARCHAR(2),
    @pageSize INT,
    @startRowIndex INT

AS BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @daysCount INT
    SELECT @daysCount = 
        CASE WHEN @mon IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN @tue IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN @wed IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN @thu IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN @fri IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN @sat IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN @sun IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 

    SELECT
          Rec
        , calories
        , overallPreparationTime
        , isFavouriteWhenGeneratingMenu
    FROM (
        SELECT
            (
                SELECT [Count] = COUNT(d3.recipeId) 
                FROM dbo.DailyContentDish d3
                WHERE
                (
                    ISNULL(@mon, weekDayId) = weekDayId OR
                    ISNULL(@tue, weekDayId) = weekDayId OR
                    ISNULL(@wed, weekDayId) = weekDayId OR
                    ISNULL(@thu, weekDayId) = weekDayId OR
                    ISNULL(@fri, weekDayId) = weekDayId OR
                    ISNULL(@sat, weekDayId) = weekDayId OR
                    ISNULL(@sun, weekDayId) = weekDayId 
                ) AND d3.recipeId = d.recipeId 
                GROUP BY d3.recipeId
            ) AS cnt, 
            d.dailyContentDishId,
            d.recipeId AS Rec, 
            title, 
            150 AS calories, 
            defaultSmallImagePath,
            activePreparationTime + passivePreparationTime AS overallPreparationTime,
            CASE WHEN d2.dailyContentDishId IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isFavouriteWhenGeneratingMenu
        FROM dbo.DailyContentDish d
        LEFT JOIN dbo.RecipesTranslations r ON r.recipeId = d.recipeId
        LEFT JOIN dbo.RecipeAdditionalInformation t ON t.recipeId = d.recipeId
        LEFT JOIN dbo.DailyContentDishFavourite d2 ON d.dailyContentDishId = d2.dailyContentDishId
        WHERE isEnabled = 1 
            AND mealId = @mealId 
            AND (       
                weekDayId = @mon OR
                weekDayId = @tue OR
                weekDayId = @wed OR
                weekDayId = @thu OR
                weekDayId = @fri OR
                weekDayId = @sat OR
                weekDayId = @sun
            )
    ) p
    WHERE p.cnt = @daysCount

END
```

**Small off-top:**

This:

```
AND (       
    weekDayId = @mon OR
    weekDayId = @tue OR
    weekDayId = @wed OR
    weekDayId = @thu OR
    weekDayId = @fri OR
    weekDayId = @sat OR
    weekDayId = @sun
)
```

Possible optimize to this:

```
weekDayId % @weekDay = 0
```

If @mon, @tue is *not null* and contains 1, 2, ...

Comment: For now it gives me error on cnt = SELECT and at last )
Also: at "LEFT JOIN dbo.DailyContentDishFavourite d2 ON t.dailyContentDishId = d2.dailyContentDishId" it can not find t.dailyContentDishId.
Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Updated answer is a looot beter: There is only one more mistake:
LEFT JOIN dbo.DailyContentDishFavourite d2 ON t.dailyContentDishId = d2.dailyContentDishId. It doesn't recognize "t.dailyContentDishId" after ON statement.

Comment: I already fix it: d.dailyContentDishId = d2.dailyContentDishId

Comment: Please, see my last changes.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out. Now it gives me error (when I run):
sg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetDailyContentDish, Line 61
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. :(

Comment: Sorry by I can't see any GetDailyContentDish in your code sample.

Comment: GetDailyContentDish is the name of stored procedure. You have been very helpful so far, I just don't understand how this is not working :(

Comment: This new version doesn't return anything :(
I had more success with previous version. I have also updated my question in order to be more understandable. Hope it helps you to understand better.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT
        ( -- For count
         SELECT COUNT(d.recipeId) AS [Count]
         FROM DailyContentDish d
         WHERE (
                ISNULL(@amon, d.weekDayId) = d.weekDayId OR
                ISNULL(@tue, d.weekDayId) = d.weekDayId OR
                ISNULL(@wed, d.weekDayId) = d.weekDayId OR
                ISNULL(@thu, d.weekDayId) = d.weekDayId OR
                ISNULL(@fri, d.weekDayId) = d.weekDayId OR
                ISNULL(@sat, d.weekDayId) = d.weekDayId OR
                ISNULL(@sun, d.weekDayId) = d.weekDayId 
                ) AND d.recipeId = DailyContentDish.recipeId
          GROUP BY d.recipeId
          ) AS cnt, 
          -- End for count
          DailyContentDish.dailyContentDishId,
          DailyContentDish.recipeId AS Rec, 
          title, 
          150 AS calories, 
          defaultSmallImagePath,
          activePreparationTime + passivePreparationTime AS overallPreparationTime,
          CAST(
               CASE WHEN EXISTS
               (
                SELECT  DailyContentDishFavourite.dailyContentDishFavouriteId
                FROM DailyContentDishFavourite 
                WHERE DailyContentDishFavourite.dailyContentDishId = DailyContentDish.dailyContentDishId
                )
                    THEN 1 
                    ELSE 0
                END 
                AS BIT) AS isFavouriteWhenGeneratingMenu
         FROM DailyContentDish
           LEFT OUTER JOIN
             RecipesTranslations ON RecipesTranslations.recipeId = DailyContentDish.recipeId
           LEFT OUTER JOIN
             RecipeAdditionalInformation ON RecipeAdditionalInformation.recipeId = DailyContentDish.recipeId
         WHERE
           isEnabled = 1 AND
           mealId=@mealId AND 
             (       
              weekDayId=@mon OR
              weekDayId=@tue OR
              weekDayId=@wed OR
              weekDayId=@thu OR
              weekDayId=@fri OR
              weekDayId=@sat OR
              weekDayId=@sun
              )        
        ) p
WHERE p.cnt = @daysCount
```

UPDATE 21.05.2013(added Demo)

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#weekDays') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.#weekDays     
SELECT weekDayId
INTO dbo.#weekDays
FROM(VALUES(@mon),
           (@tue),
           (@wed),
           (@thu),
           (@fri),
           (@sat),
           (@sun))x(weekDayId)
WHERE weekDayId IS NOT NULL

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX x ON dbo.#weekDays(weekDayId)

SELECT d.dailyContentDishId,
       d.recipeId AS Rec, 
       title, 
       150 AS calories, 
       defaultSmallImagePath,
       activePreparationTime + passivePreparationTime AS overallPreparationTime,
       CASE WHEN f.dailyContentDishId IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isFavouriteWhenGeneratingMen
FROM DailyContentDish d
  LEFT JOIN RecipesTranslations ON RecipesTranslations.recipeId = d.recipeId
  LEFT JOIN RecipeAdditionalInformation ON RecipeAdditionalInformation.recipeId = d.recipeId
  LEFT JOIN dbo.DailyContentDishFavourite f ON d.dailyContentDishId = f.dailyContentDishId
WHERE d.isEnabled = 1 AND d.mealId = @mealId 
  AND NOT EXISTS(          
                 SELECT d3.weekDayId
                 FROM dbo.#weekDays d3
                 EXCEPT
                 SELECT d2.WeekDayId
                 FROM DailyContentDish d2
                 WHERE d.recipeId = d2.recipeId 
                   AND d2.isEnabled = 1 AND d2.mealId = @mealId 
                 )
```

Simple demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35441/6)

Comment: @CyberHawk Try the new version of the script;)

Comment: Close to solution.
It is returning recipes approximately as it should. I'll try to explain: For Monday I have stored recipes (ID) 1,2,3, and 4. For Tuesday recipe 3, for Saturday recipe with ID 2 and Sunday 1, 2 and 4. If I select Monday I get 1,1, 2, 2 (repeated, but the count of recipe is correct). If I select Tuesday I get recipe 3 (correct). Saturday 2 - OK.  Mon + Sat should give me 1,2, and 4 but gives me 1, 1 and 2 - but count of returned recipes is again OK.
I think this needs just a little tweak and it should work.
If I select additional day nothing is returned - again OK.

Comment: Moday: 1,1,2,2. Sunday: 1,1,2. Mon + SAT = 1,1,2.  MON + TUE = 3 = OK

Comment: but the demo works well(Added demo to clarify your question().

Comment: Awesome! I will test this, and hope to figure it out why it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

> only meals which are the same for that days (and meals) should be
>   returned

What is missing is the correlation of the outer query to the count calculation in your inner query. I.e. the following:

```
( DC1.WeekDayId In( @Mon, @Tue, @Wed, @Thu, @Fri, @Sat, @Sun )
    Or Coalesce( @Mon, @Tue, @Wed, @Thu, @Fri, @Sat, @Sun ) Is Null )
And DC1.MealId = DC.MealId
```

You need to alias at least one of the tables to make this happen. Typically, it is easier to read if you alias the tables on both the inner and outer query. The other item missing is that the seven variables for each day represent ticks ("select this day") instead of the day itself. If we change that, it makes the query simpler.

```
Select @Mon = Case When @Mon Is Not Null Then 1 End
    , @Tue = Case When @Tue Is Not Null Then 2 End
    , @Wed = Case When @Wed Is Not Null Then 3 End
    , @Thu = Case When @Thu Is Not Null Then 4 End
    , @Fri = Case When @Fri Is Not Null Then 5 End
    , @Sat = Case When @Sat Is Not Null Then 6 End
    , @Sun = Case When @Sun Is Not Null Then 7 End;

 Select Count(*) Over() As CountOfResults
    ,   (
        Select Count(*)
        From DailyContentDish As DC1
        Where DC1.weekDayId = DC.weekDayId
        ) As CountOfDishesOnDay
    ,   (
        Select Count(Distinct mealId)
        From DailyContentDish As DC1
        Where DC1.weekDayId = DC.weekDayId
        ) As CountOfMeals           
    , DC.DailyContentDishId
    , DC.RecipeId As Rec
    , Title
    , 150 As Calories
    , DefaultsMallImagePath
    , ActivePreparationTime 
        + PassivePreparationTime As OverallPreparationTime
    , Cast  (
            Case 
            When Exists (
                        Select 1
                        From DailyContentDishFavourite As DF1
                        Where DF1.DailyContentDishId = DC.DailyContentDishId
                        ) Then 1 
            Else 0
            End 
            As Bit) As IsFavouriteWhenGeneratingMenu
From DailyContentDish As DC
    Left Join RecipesTranslations As RT
        On RT.RecipeId = DC.RecipeId
    Left Join RecipeAdditionalInformation As RA
        On RA.RecipeId = DC.RecipeId
Where DC.IsEnabled = 1 
    And DC.MealId=@MealId 
    And DC.WeekDayId In( @Mon, @Tue, @Wed, @Thu, @Fri, @Sat, @Sun )
```

**Addition**

If the daily variables are supposed to represent a count of results per day returned (e.g., if `@Mon = 2`, then we should get back two rows for Monday), then you could do something like so:

```
Declare @DailyParameters Table
    (
    DayCount int not null
    , DayOfWeek int not null
    )

Insert @DailyParameters( DayCount, DayOfWeek )
Select Z.Cnt, Z.DayOfWeek
From    (
        Select @Mon As Cnt, 1 As DayOfWeek
        Union All Select @Tue, 2
        Union All Select @Wed, 3
        Union All Select @Thu, 4
        Union All Select @Fri, 5
        Union All Select @Sat, 6
        Union All Select @Sun, 7
        ) As Z
Where Z.Cnt Is Not Null
```

The Where clause would then change to something like so:

```
Where DC.IsEnabled = 1 
    And DC.MealId = @MealId 
    And DC.WeekDayId In( Select DayOfWeek From @DailyParameters )
    And (
        Select Count(*)
        From DailyContentDish As DC1
        Where DC1.weekDayId = DC.weekDayId
        ) = (
            Select D1.DayCount
            From @DailyParameters As D1
            Where D1.DayOfWeek = DC.weekDayId
            )
```

Comment: I have a feeling you are pointing to the missing puzzle. The solution that Alexander Fedorenko above gave is pretty close, since it is giving me all entries which are repeated twice if I select 2 days, or all entries which are repeated 3 times if i select 3 days.
Will test this ASAP and let you all know. THANKS A BUNCH!

Comment: I've updated my response. I think the part that is throwing everyone is the value of the daily variables. Are those ticks? Are those counts per day that need to be returned? If the later, what do the counts represent: meals, days, rows in DailyContentDish?

Comment: @mon = MondayId (stored in different datatable). ID of Monday = 1, ID of Tuesday = 2 and so on. Counts are rows (with same recipeId) in dailyContentDish. Count's don't need to be returned (it is just a helping tool for me), it's just that I would like to select items, which are the same for days selected. If I select Mon and Sat (ID = 1 and 6 - all others are null) then I would like to select all entries from dailyContentDish which have dayId 1 or 6.

Comment: @CyberHawk - If that's the case, then my first solution should work.

Answer (score 0):

"*Since entries with recipeId are entered more then once I would like to know how many times are they entered.*"

Base on this statement I would just use the OVER clause with COUNT.

Something like:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY recipeId) AS 'cnt'
  FROM DailyContentDish
```

I would need more details about the tables and what the output should be in order to provide more details.

Here is more info on the OVER clause in 2008: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461(v=sql.105).aspx

Example using COUNT with OVER: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/08/11/sql-server-tips-from-the-sql-joes-2-pros-development-series-advanced-aggregates-with-the-over-clause-day-11-of-35/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
It says that COUNT needs 1 argument.

Comment: Use COUNT(*) instead of COUNT()

Comment: I have added database diagram, hope it helps clarify things a bit.